# Firefox Bootstrapped Extensions: Namespace

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I am looking into bootstrapped extensions. Looking at the code of some of those extensions, I see a lot of variables, constants & functions declarations.

Are they all declared in window object?
Isn't there an issue with namespace pollution/clash?

I wrap every single thing in *one* object/namespace in the overlay extensions that I have done.
Are bootstrapped extension different in that regard?

I have noticed that all `bootstrapped.js` use the same/standard function names. Does that mean that bootstrapped extensions are sandboxed or their scope enclosed?

Comment: Your guess is correct, `bootstrap.js` is loaded into a sandbox.

Comment: Download a bootstrapped addon like `Profilist` and then use `XPIScope` to log to console what is in it. Paste this code in scratchpad and then inspect the object dumped you'll see everything you want to leanr about whats in the bootstrap sandbox: `var XPIScope = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm');
var scope = XPIScope.XPIProvider.bootstrapScopes['Profilist@jetpack'];
console.info('bootstrap scope=', scope)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The `bootstrap.js` scope

> Are they all declared in window object? Isn't there an issue with namespace pollution/clash?
>
> ...
>
> I have noticed that all bootstrapped.js use the same/standard function names. Does that mean that bootstrapped extensions are sandboxed or their scope enclosed?

To expand on the @paa comment: `bootstrap.js` does indeed get it's own scope.

The `AddonManager` will create a new scope (or "namespace" if you like) per bootstrap.js. Right now the implementation uses `Components.utils.Sandbox`, but that is an implementation detail.

This means that there is no `window` object. `bootstrap.js` will be loaded once per Firefox process and has no `window` object. This is very much unlike overlay script which will be loaded once per new window and share a common scope (the `window` object itself) with Firefox code and overlay scripts from other add-ons.

That also means bootstrapped add-ons are free to choose whatever names they like in their scope (their personal *sand box*) without fear of clashing with other add-ons, as long as the names are valid in Javascript in general.

The only exceptions being

- the entry point function names the add-on must implement that the Add-on Manager will call and therefore have special meaning (`startup`, `shutdown`, `install`, `uninstall`),
- pre-defined stuff that either comes with the `Sandbox` (`Components`, and Javascript built-ins like `Object`, `String`, `Array`, `Map`, etc.)
- stuff that the `AddonManager` will inject (like the `__SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__`, `ADDON_*`, `APP_*` constants).

A full list of pre-defined names, as of Firefox 30:

```
Components.utils.reportError(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).join(", "));

// Object, Function, eval, Components, XPCNativeWrapper, dump, debug,
// importFunction, IDBCursor, IDBCursorWithValue, EventTarget, IDBDatabase,
// IDBFactory, FileHandle, IDBFileHandle, IDBIndex, IDBKeyRange,
// IDBObjectStore, IDBRequest, IDBOpenDBRequest, IDBTransaction, Event,
// IDBVersionChangeEvent, indexedDB, APP_STARTUP, APP_SHUTDOWN, ADDON_ENABLE,
// ADDON_DISABLE, ADDON_INSTALL, ADDON_UNINSTALL, ADDON_UPGRADE,
// ADDON_DOWNGRADE, Worker, ChromeWorker, __SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__, undefined,
// Array, Boolean, JSON, Date, Math, isNaN, isFinite, parseFloat, parseInt,
// NaN, Infinity, Number, String, escape, unescape, uneval, decodeURI,
// encodeURI, decodeURIComponent, encodeURIComponent, RegExp, Error,
// InternalError, EvalError, RangeError, ReferenceError, SyntaxError,
// TypeError, URIError, Iterator, StopIteration, Int8Array, Uint8Array,
// Int16Array, Uint16Array, Int32Array, Uint32Array, Float32Array,
// Float64Array, Uint8ClampedArray, DataView, ArrayBuffer, Proxy, WeakMap,
// Map, Set, Intl
```

### Manipulating other scopes

*However*, bootstrapped add-on still need to be considerate and avoid clashes when interacting with **other scopes**, such as windows, JS code modules, other add-on bootstrap scopes and so on. Manipulating other scopes may also cause leaks of the add-on bootstrap scope.

E.g.

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.foo = "bar";
```

This will add a `foo` property to the `Services` object that lives in the shared `Services.jsm` code module.
All other add-ons and the browser code will see `Services.foo` as well, so it might cause clashes and regular *don't pollute the shared namespace*-rules apply.

Also, when your add-on gets `shutdown` you'd have to delete `Services.foo` again, or else the `Services.jsm` scope would keep a reference to it and since the value of `foo` (the string `"bar"`) lives within your bootstrap compartment, it would keep alive your bootstrap compartment due to that reference and effectively create a memory leak otherwise (called [*Zombie compartments*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Zombie_compartments) in mozilla slang).

Or

```
// Get the most recent browser window
var browserWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
browserWindow.doSomething = function() {
  browserWindow.alert("hello world");
};
```

This would be equivalent to having an overlay script of:

```
function doSomething() {
  alert("hello world");
}
```

Both would add a new name `doSomething` to the browser window scope, hence that name might clash with other add-ons and *don't pollute the shared namespace*-rules apply.
And again, this might leak the same way than the previous example, so a bootstrapped add-on will have to delete the property on `shutdown` again to avoid that.

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you nmaier. BTW, stackoverflow can do with a **firefox-addon-bootstrapped** tag

Comment: firefox-addon-bootstrapped is too long (25 chars limit). Instead I just tagged this question with firefox-addon-restartless. Let's see if that tag sticks.

Comment: Where can I find a full list of constants "that the AddonManager will inject"?

Comment: I don't think there is really an up-to-date list, but it is mostly the [Reason constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#Reason_constants) plus `__SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__` (and some things that the `Sandbox` usually omits, namely `*Worker`). You can try to `Components.utils.reportError(Object.keys(this));` which should give the things not usually in present in a `Sandbox`.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually interested in `ADDON_*`, `APP_*`. I have seen `APP_SELF`. In my overlay addons, I grab data from _install.rdf_ I want to know if they are available via above 2 constant sets. Also, can above ie `Components.utils.reportError(Object.keys(this));` be run outside an extension? how?

Comment: That line is supposed to be run in `bootstrap.js`

Comment: 1- Is there a way in bootstrapped extension to get extensions own Name (not using AddonManger)? 2- How do I get a _nsIURI_ for _install.rdf_ to be read by _XHR_? `resource://` is not available in bootstrapped _chrome.manifest_.

Comment: This comment thread is getting to long and off-topic. Post new questions please.

Comment: Yeah make seperate topic. But answer to that is in `function startup(aData, aReason) { console.log(aData) }` aData argument holds all the info you want on name etc.

Comment: Sadly, *aData* does not have the *name*

Comment: @nmaier Does the scope enclosure apply to CustomEvent too? Can the same CustomEvent name be used in different addons without clashing?

Comment: event names are always global. So if you dispatch `some-event`, all other handlers for `some-event` in the same element tree will see it.